# Why when i add the src to image using jQuery custom plugin, the paragraph is getting moved down?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

Here is my code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Box using Plugin</title>
    <script>
        (function ($) {
            $.fn.boxPlugin = function (options) {
                //default values
                var settings = $.extend({
                    color: "green",
                    width: "100px",
                    height: "100px",
                    backgroundColor: "black",
                    imageURL: "",
                    display: "inline-block"

                }, options);

                $(this).addClass('boxAdded').css({ "color": settings.color, "width": settings.width, "height": settings.height, "background": settings.backgroundColor, "display": settings.display }).find('img').attr('src', settings.imageURL);
            }
        }(jQuery));
    </script>
    <style>
        p {
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".box").boxPlugin({ width: "200px", height: "200px", backgroundColor: "lightblue" });
            $("#boxOne").boxPlugin({ width: "200px", height: "200px", backgroundColor: "lightblue", imageURL: "https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" });
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p class="box"></p>
    <p class="box"></p>
    <p class="box"></p>
    <p id="boxOne">
        <img src="" />
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

If i don't add imageURL to option then width, height are set and it works just fine.

But when i add the imageURL option the image gets linked to its source but the paragraph get moved down a little why is this happening? So strange!

Thanks.

Comment: give `vertical-align: top;` to `#boxOne`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the `display:block;` to img to fit with the box. Because your all block are `inline-block`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Box using Plugin</title>
    <script>
        (function ($) {
            $.fn.boxPlugin = function (options) {
                //default values
                var settings = $.extend({
                    color: "green",
                    width: "100px",
                    height: "100px",
                    backgroundColor: "black",
                    imageURL: "",
                    display: "inline-block"

                }, options);

                $(this).addClass('boxAdded').css({ 
                "color": settings.color, 
                "width": settings.width, 
                "height": settings.height, 
                "background": settings.backgroundColor, 
                "display": settings.display }).find('img').attr('src', settings.imageURL).css('display',settings.imgdisplay);
            }
        }(jQuery));
    </script>
    <style>
        p {
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".box").boxPlugin({ width: "200px", height: "200px", backgroundColor: "lightblue" });
            $("#boxOne").boxPlugin({ 
            width: "200px", 
            height: "200px", 
            backgroundColor: "lightblue", 
            imageURL: "https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" ,
            imgdisplay: "block"
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p class="box"></p>
    <p class="box"></p>
    <p class="box"></p>
    <p id="boxOne">
        <img src=""  />
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Even though other people answers are correct your answer is exactly what i wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Change your `CSS` to :

```
p {
   margin: 0px;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Box using Plugin</title>
    <script>
        (function ($) {
            $.fn.boxPlugin = function (options) {
                //default values
                var settings = $.extend({
                    color: "green",
                    width: "100px",
                    height: "100px",
                    backgroundColor: "black",
                    imageURL: "",
                    display: "inline-block"

                }, options);

                $(this).addClass('boxAdded').css({ "color": settings.color, "width": settings.width, "height": settings.height, "background": settings.backgroundColor, "display": settings.display }).find('img').attr('src', settings.imageURL);
            }
        }(jQuery));
    </script>
    <style>
        p {
            margin: 0px;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".box").boxPlugin({ width: "200px", height: "200px", backgroundColor: "lightblue" });
            $("#boxOne").boxPlugin({ width: "200px", height: "200px", backgroundColor: "lightblue", imageURL: "https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" });
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p class="box"></p>
    <p class="box"></p>
    <p class="box"></p>
    <p id="boxOne">
        <img src="" />
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but there is no white space..Meanwhile i am not the downvoter

Comment: in question you can see four blocks.In your answer it showing only two..i think you need to do the css only for `boxOne id`

Comment: I am still confuse I used the same snippet and just add the one line of code and I can see four blocks here, there is no such indication to use css only for `boxOne`

Comment: You see in my question that each boxes are separated but in your answer top two boxes and bottom two boxes doesn't have any space between them which makes them looks like two boxes. This is what others are saying.

Comment: got it, I was looking this at full page mode

Answer (score 0):

use para inside  tag and it will arranged Ur data in well manner,
due to image shadow it happen

Answer (score 0):

Just Insert :

```
#boxOne img {
   position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Box using Plugin</title>
    <script>
        (function ($) {
            $.fn.boxPlugin = function (options) {
                //default values
                var settings = $.extend({
                    color: "green",
                    width: "100px",
                    height: "100px",
                    backgroundColor: "black",
                    imageURL: "",
                    display: "inline-block"

                }, options);

                $(this).addClass('boxAdded').css({ "color": settings.color, "width": settings.width, "height": settings.height, "background": settings.backgroundColor, "display": settings.display }).find('img').attr('src', settings.imageURL);
            }
        }(jQuery));
    </script>
    <style>
        p {
            margin: 0px;
        }
        #boxOne img {
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".box").boxPlugin({ width: "200px", height: "200px", backgroundColor: "lightblue" });
            $("#boxOne").boxPlugin({ width: "200px", height: "200px", backgroundColor: "lightblue", imageURL: "https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" });
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p class="box"></p>
    <p class="box"></p>
    <p class="box"></p>
    <p id="boxOne">
        <img src="" />
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add style property of p tag float to left.

```
p {
   margin: 0px;
   float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `vertical-align: top;` to `#boxOne`.

It is better to give the `vertical-align: top;` with `display: inline-block`.
The default the value `vertical-align` is considered as `baseline`.